# jquery redirect after post

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, post, redirect

I have 3 php files.

- file1.php contains PHP + HTML design and jQuery scripts.
- file2.php contains just PHP and mySQL processing
- file3.php generates a PDF using TCPDF, based on 2 variables that it receives in $_REQUEST, and displays the resulting PDF

  1. I call from a button in **file1.php** a $.post towards **file2.php**.
  2. Some data processing happens in **file2.php** (mysql inserts and updates) and I obtain **var1** and **var2**.
  3. When processing is done in **file2.php** I want to go and display the PDF that is created by **file3.php** based on **var1** and **var2**

So the jQuery code in **file1.php** where I call post is:

```
        $("#saveinv").click(function() { // button is clicked
            var listview_array = new Array();
            // here I populate the array with values then...
            $.post("file2.php", 
               {json: JSON.stringify(listview_array)}, 
               function(data){alert("success"); 
            });
        });
```

In file2.php there is nothing to see. After much processing, I end up with 2 variables that help me call the **file3.php**

**file3.php** must be called with 2 params: var1 and var2 so something like:

```
file3.php?var1=5&var2=77
```

But I have no idea where to place the call or what exact syntax to use. I tried different solutions without success. Maybe I was doing it wrong and you can help me.

- I tried to place at the end of file2.php a header('Location: file3.php?var1=5&var2=77');
- I tried to :

  - add at the end of file2.php the line : **return 'file3.php?var1=5&var2=77';**
  - then replace the alert('success') in file1.php with **window.location = data.redirect** but I keep getting redirected to "undefined".
- If I do **window.location='file3.php?var1=5&var2=77'** in file1.php then all works perfect, but I need those variables to be sent from file2.php. They are not constants.

What should I do, and where?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to redirect to another file, there is no reason to use ajax, the only thing you will be doing, is making 2 requests to the server instead of one. You should do a normal (non-ajax) post and combine `file2` and `file3`.

Comment: I went with your idea even though the other comments seemed also viable. However I cannot accept your answer unless you make it and answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

Just put your result as JSON in file2.php:

```
echo '({"var1":"1","va2":"2"})';
```

where you get it as `data` inside your ajax callback function in file1.php, then use `eval`

```
var args = eval(data);
window.location = 'file3.php?var1=' + args.var1 + '&var2=' + args.var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

add at the end of file2.php the line : `return 'file3.php?var1=5&var2=77';`

You cannot use `return`, just use `print` or `echo` and it should work.